# Error in i.parse.plot.params(graph, list(…))

Tags: plot, igraph

reading about market basket analysis using R, I used the code provided in Salem Marafi's fine blog (http://www.salemmarafi.com/code/market-basket-analysis-with-r/comment-page-1/#comment-81662). The final code

```
library(arulesViz)
plot(rules,method="graph",interactive=TRUE,shading=NA)
```

for producing a net-like graph (see image)

[image]

however produces the following error message:

**Error in i.parse.plot.params(graph, list(…)) :
object ‘v.color’ not found**

I use R 3.1.2 binary for Mac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks) and higher. Therefore I also

- re-installed XQuartz,
- as well as the packages igraph and
- tcltk

(Note: capabilities(“tcltk”) result is TRUE => tcltk package should be properly installed and working).

I am very grateful for any advice on the source that causes this error message and how to solve this. 
Thanks a a lot for any thoughts!

Cheers, Lucie

Answer (score 2):

Faced the same problem as yours, just removed the "shading=NA" or playing around like "shading=T" and I get a graph, though not the one that Salem Marafi shows.!